# Finding the 10 closest values to 100 and the 30 closest ones to 30

Tags: r, loops

I have the variables price (dollars) and size (sq.feet). From my dataset, I want to find the 10 houses that best fit the description "price close to 100 and size close to 30".
I can see that I have to use the abs() function, and find the smallest absolute difference. However, I want both conditions to be true at the same time, I don't know how to do that with abs.
I thought about doing

```
which(abs(...))
```

but I don't know how.

Any ideas?

The data:

```
data_struct <-
  structure(
    list(
      new_baltimore.SQFT = c(
        11.25,
        28.92,
        30.62,
        26.12,
        22.04,
        39.42,
        21.88,
        25.6,
        44.12,
        19.88,
        12.08,
        10.99,
        12.8,
        29.79,
        14.3,
        13.72,
        11.84,
        18.06,
        10.72,
        8.96,
        14.38,
        36.75,
        20,
        22.82,
        24.86,
        19.2,
        11.58,
        26,
        14.4,
        11.62,
        23.08,
        23.76,
        15.6,
        10,
        22.8,
        16.76,
        22.1,
        14.28,
        15.36,
        16,
        23.04,
        24.94,
        11.82,
        12.88,
        11.2,
        18.12,
        38.25,
        17.68,
        19.02,
        32.8,
        15.16,
        21.975,
        12.6,
        23.52,
        17.52,
        47.61,
        20.55,
        35.52,
        8.4,
        13.68,
        14.48,
        12.8,
        12.8,
        18,
        15.4,
        10.08,
        8.96,
        8.96,
        20,
        12.88,
        12,
        18.16,
        14.28,
        26,
        12.02,
        20.8,
        11.78,
        8.68,
        17.6,
        11.4,
        44.55,
        46.32,
        10.24,
        9.6,
        31.2,
        26.4,
        13.6,
        27.48,
        17.86,
        18.04,
        14.84,
        10.46,
        14.56,
        6.96,
        9.5,
        11.86,
        12.88,
        12.32,
        6.72,
        10.08,
        15.6,
        6.72,
        11.52,
        11.76,
        10.24,
        11.52,
        9.28,
        6.72,
        15.6,
        15.5,
        9.84,
        15.6,
        13.76,
        10.24,
        5.76,
        10.08,
        11.52,
        12.15,
        9.77,
        15,
        14.4,
        14.5,
        22.54,
        10.24,
        7.8,
        8.4,
        10.92,
        42.9,
        9,
        10.5,
        10.08,
        12.6,
        8.96,
        8.58,
        7.56,
        10.8,
        13.44,
        10.24,
        14.44,
        12.24,
        13.2,
        9.6,
        15.22,
        24.16,
        10.24,
        10.24,
        9.88,
        23.2,
        17.68,
        24.3,
        35.94,
        21.6,
        11.02,
        21,
        23.92,
        14.4,
        28,
        11.44,
        21.94,
        10.24,
        16.86,
        9.92,
        13.44,
        12,
        14.76,
        8.96,
        11.52,
        8.64,
        8.12,
        11.12,
        11.28,
        10.36,
        11.52,
        17.1,
        17.52,
        10.73,
        11.2,
        12.8,
        12,
        41.07,
        12.8,
        22.36,
        10.56,
        13.44,
        11.02,
        17.98,
        18.88,
        11.76,
        9.36,
        11.52,
        27.3,
        23.04,
        17.68,
        13.36,
        11.6,
        11.52,
        9.98,
        12.96,
        11.13,
        19.6,
        11.52,
        12.16,
        0,
        10.64
      ),
      new_baltimore.PRICE = c(
        47,
        113,
        165,
        104.3,
        62.5,
        70,
        127.5,
        64.5,
        145,
        63.5,
        58.9,
        65,
        48,
        3.5,
        12.8,
        17.5,
        36,
        41.9,
        53.5,
        24.5,
        24.5,
        55.5,
        60,
        51,
        46,
        46,
        44,
        54.9,
        42.5,
        44,
        44.9,
        37.9,
        33,
        43.9,
        49.6,
        52,
        37.5,
        50,
        35.9,
        42.9,
        107,
        112,
        44.9,
        55,
        102,
        35.5,
        62.9,
        39,
        110,
        8,
        62,
        85.9,
        57,
        110,
        67.7,
        89.5,
        70,
        74,
        13,
        48,
        24,
        53.5,
        34.5,
        53,
        87.5,
        33.5,
        24,
        9.6,
        30,
        41,
        30,
        38.9,
        20.7,
        49.9,
        18.6,
        39,
        34,
        16,
        18.9,
        15.2,
        41.5,
        53,
        22,
        24.9,
        6.7,
        32.5,
        30,
        59,
        29.5,
        26,
        16.5,
        39,
        48.9,
        33.5,
        46,
        54,
        57.9,
        37.9,
        32,
        31,
        34,
        29,
        32.5,
        51.9,
        31,
        41.8,
        48,
        28,
        35,
        46.5,
        51.9,
        35.4,
        16,
        35,
        35,
        36.5,
        35.9,
        45,
        40,
        35,
        38,
        37,
        23,
        25.5,
        39.5,
        21.5,
        9,
        67.5,
        13.4,
        12.5,
        28.5,
        23,
        33.5,
        9,
        11,
        30.9,
        31.65,
        33,
        33.4,
        47,
        40,
        46,
        45.5,
        57,
        29.9,
        30,
        34,
        51,
        64.5,
        57.5,
        85.5,
        61,
        38,
        56.5,
        60.4,
        51.5,
        54,
        69,
        56,
        27.9,
        37.5,
        32.9,
        22,
        29.9,
        39.9,
        32.6,
        38.5,
        21.5,
        25.9,
        27.5,
        22.9,
        31.5,
        8.5,
        5.5,
        33,
        57,
        47,
        43.5,
        43.9,
        68.5,
        44.25,
        61,
        40,
        44.5,
        57,
        35,
        35.1,
        64.5,
        40,
        42.6,
        50,
        58,
        58,
        55,
        43,
        54,
        39,
        45,
        42,
        38.9,
        43.215,
        26.5,
        30,
        29.5
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-204L)
  )
```

Comment: You need to settle on a distance metric. In 2 equally weighted dimensions, we normally use Euclidean distance which squares the difference in each dimension and adds them up (and then takes the square root, but you don't have to bother with that to rank them). You could instead `abs()` the difference in each dimension and add them up. Or you could weight them somehow (maybe based on their relative variances), so a difference of 1 in size counts more or less than a difference of 1 in price.

Comment: But overall, this seems like a homework or learning problem. I've given you something to think about. I'd love to see some code and attempts from you before helping more. We generally expect homework problems to demonstrate a good bit of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right with `abs`olute differences. Try to subtract price and size to get a zero point, similar to de-meaning. Using `replicate` we subtract a respective matrix. From the absolute differences first `rank` the columns then again the `rowSums`. The first `k` values of the `order` should give you the desired appartements!

```
f <- \(price, size, k, data) {
  aux <- abs(data - t(replicate(nrow(data), c(size, price))))
  data[order(rank(rowSums(as.data.frame(lapply(aux, rank)))))[1:k], ]
}

f(price=100, size=30, k=10, data=data_struct[1:2])
#     new_baltimore.SQFT new_baltimore.PRICE
# 2               28.920               113.0
# 4               26.120               104.3
# 42              24.940               112.0
# 54              23.520               110.0
# 58              35.520                74.0
# 41              23.040               107.0
# 151             35.940                85.5
# 8               25.600                64.5
# 88              27.480                59.0
# 52              21.975                85.9
```

Comment: thank you! Because I don't understand, what does "replicate(nrow(data), c(size, price))" create and how is that useful? Also, isn't the matrix too big to subtract from "data"? And why did we sum the rows?

Comment: @Anna You may try `replicate(nrow(data_struct), c(size=30, price=100))` to see what it does, it has exact same size as data_struct. We subtract from each size 30 and from each price 100 and thus center the data. In the rows we sum the `rank`s according to the smallest distances from zero, and with help of `order` we may extract the `k` best ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
data_struct[head(order(pdist::pdist(data_struct, c(30,100))@dist),10), ]

    new_baltimore.SQFT new_baltimore.PRICE
4               26.120               104.3
41              23.040               107.0
54              23.520               110.0
42              24.940               112.0
2               28.920               113.0
49              19.020               110.0
151             35.940                85.5
52              21.975                85.9
45              11.200               102.0
65              15.400                87.5
```

using `tidyverse` you could do:

```
data_struct %>%
   mutate(price_diff = (new_baltimore.PRICE -100)^2,
          size_diff = (new_baltimore.SQFT-30)^2) %>%
   slice_min(price_diff + size_diff, n=10) %>%
   select(-ends_with('diff'))

   new_baltimore.SQFT new_baltimore.PRICE
1              26.120               104.3
2              23.040               107.0
3              23.520               110.0
4              24.940               112.0
5              28.920               113.0
6              19.020               110.0
7              35.940                85.5
8              21.975                85.9
9              11.200               102.0
10             15.400                87.5
```

in base R:

```
data_struct[head(order(colSums((t(data_struct) - c(30, 100))^2)), 10),]
    new_baltimore.SQFT new_baltimore.PRICE
4               26.120               104.3
41              23.040               107.0
54              23.520               110.0
42              24.940               112.0
2               28.920               113.0
49              19.020               110.0
151             35.940                85.5
52              21.975                85.9
45              11.200               102.0
65              15.400                87.5
```